# Density plot cut off and remove additional line in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I want to remove the horizontal green line on the picture, how do I do this?

I used `ggplot2` for this graph, and this is the output of a Shiny application.

[image]

```
p1 <- ggplot(dat = dat, aes(x = as.numeric(dura), col = TYPE_DE_TERMINAL)) + 
  stat_ecdf(geom = "step") +
  scale_colour_brewer(name = "Terminal", palette = "Set1") +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 15), legend.justification = c(1, 0),
        legend.position = c(1, 0), axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust=1)) + 
  ylab("CDF") + xlab("Duration") + theme_bw() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,1), labels= percent) +
  ggtitle("Cumulative distribution function of 3G connections duration (in s)") +  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0, 50))


print(p1)
```

[image]

This is the str() of my dat.

[image]

Comment: Mostafa can you point out what columns are in dat. Do you still get a line even if  you plot just one (eg the Portatif)  column? Something to try - A possible hack may be to make the scale y start from 0.00001 to 1 to drop it.

Comment: Sorry I did an error, I will edit my post. Yes even with just one ("portatif"), I gett the same result ...

Comment: I just found the response, I used stat_density() instead of geom_density() and add arguments geom="line" and position="identity".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the response, I used stat_density() instead of geom_density() and add arguments geom="line" and position="identity".